# JSON format using $.ajax and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, ajax

If I use $.ajax JQuery and I call WebMethod, I get JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: idX, id2: idY }),
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    url: "/ws/Courses.asmx/GetCourses",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        RenderCourses(data.d);
    },
});
```

but JSON has "d" property.

```
function RenderCourses(data) {

    if (data.d.length > 0) {
```

If I use `json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject` in C#, hasn't the "d" property.

```
string script = "var data = " + json + "; RenderCourses(data);";
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page.GetType(), "dataVar", script, true);
```

And `RenderCourses` fails.

Any reasons?

Comment: Try `data: { id: idX, id2: idY },` in `$.ajax`

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

ADO.NET WebMethods always serialize the response like this. `d` meand "data". And you can't do anything with this.

JsonConvert.SerializeObject is a method from third party software ([Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm)). It just simple serialize your object to JSON.